# Intel HD-Grafik 4400 black flicker on external monitor (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: drivers, 18.04, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, external-monitor

I'm running a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 on a laptop that has an HD 4400 graphics card. It all works fine on the laptop's own screen, however, when hooking up an additional (1920x1200) screen via DisplayPort--HDMI I get a black flickering at irregular time intervals on that screen. The flickers usually occur every two seconds and appear to be correlated with how much is goig on on the screen.

The *Additional Drivers* tab in the *Software & Updates* window says "No additional driver availale."

Any clue on how to resolve this issue?
Thanks!

**Update**
Same question here:
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/671220

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever find a solution to this? Seems to be a similar issue here https://github.com/rolandguelle/razer-blade-stealth-linux/issues/18.